# Arithmetic on a pointer Compilation error of a C code

Tags: c, pointers, math

I am receiving the below error in the last instruction of this sample block of code

```
sdl = (struct sockaddr_dl *)(sin + 1);
```

Arithmetic on a pointer to an incomplete type 'struct sockaddr_inarp'

I removed all unnecessary code.

Can anybody help please?

```
int test(void)
{

        int mib[6];
        size_t needed;
        char *host, *lim, *buf, *next;
        struct rt_msghdr *rtm;
        struct sockaddr_inarp *sin;
        struct sockaddr_dl *sdl;

        mib[0] = CTL_NET;
        mib[1] = PF_ROUTE;
        mib[2] = 0;
        mib[3] = AF_INET;
        mib[4] = NET_RT_FLAGS;
        mib[5] = RTF_LLINFO;

        if ((buf = malloc(needed)) == NULL)
            err(1, "malloc");

        lim = buf + needed;

        for (next = buf; next < lim; next += rtm->rtm_msglen)
        {
            rtm = (struct rt_msghdr *)next;
            sin = (struct sockaddr_inarp *)(rtm + 1);
            sdl = (struct sockaddr_dl *)(sin + 1);
        }
}
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with pointer arithmetic, instead it's missing the definition of the `sockaddr_inarp` structure. Do you include the header file where it's defined?

Comment: You probably need `#include <netinet/if_ether.h>` to resolve that error. But there's more, `needed` is used without being initialized, for instance.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The error message _is_ because of pointer arithmetic.  Had code been `sdl = (struct sockaddr_dl *)(sin /* + 1 */);`, that error message "Arithmetic on a pointer to an incomplete type 'struct sockaddr_inarp'" would not have occurred.

Comment: @chux The important part of the error message is the *"incomplete type"*. That means the type `struct sockaddr_inarp` haven't been defined. It has been *declared* or there would be other errors, but it's not defined. That of course means the compiler don't know the size of the structure so pointer arithmetic can't be used, but it's still the missing structure definition that is the root cause.

Comment: thanks a lot @Someprogrammerdude. #include <net/if_types.h> was missing.  the code runs perfect on the simulator but <net/if_types.h> file not found compilation error when i try to run from iPhone.

Comment: you  removed way too much.  Where/what are the header files that are `#include`d for this code?  Are we expected to guess?

Comment: the pointer `rtm` is not initialized, so this line: `for (next = buf; next < lim; next += rtm->rtm_msglen)` has undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: the variable `needed` is not initialized, so the call to `malloc()` will return an unknown abount of heap memory  and this line: `rtm = (struct rt_msghdr *)next;` will point to some unknown location.  this line: `sin = (struct sockaddr_inarp *)(rtm + 1);` will result in the 'sin' being set to the address of `rtm` + the length of a `struct rt_msghdr` and this line: `sdl = (struct sockaddr_dl *)(sin + 1);` will result in the `sdl` being set to the address contained in `sin`+ the length of a `struct sockaddr_inarp`.  Is this really what you want?